# newline characters in scanf

Tags: c, newline, scanf

I have written below program which tries to read and print the values of a structure.
I thought that scanf ignores the /n for all kinf of data except for char but when i run the below program and provide the first input as an integer. I dont get the o/p for name variable. Why??

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
struct employee
{
    int empno;
    char name[10];
    float p_money;
};

int main()
{
    struct employee e;
    struct employee *ptr;
    ptr = &e;
    printf("please enter the empno \n");
    scanf("%d", &(ptr->empno));
    printf("please enter the name \n");
    gets(ptr->name);
    //scanf("%d", &(ptr->empno));
    printf("please enter the money \n");
    scanf("%f", &(ptr->p_money));
    printf("Roll No: %d\n", ptr->empno);
    printf("Name: %s\n", ptr->name);
    printf("Money: %f\n", ptr->p_money);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Execution:

```
please enter the empno
10 
please enter the name
please enter the money
100.99
```

Roll No: 10
    Name:
    Money: 100.989998

```
please enter the empno
10jackal
please enter the name
please enter the money
100.99
```

Roll No: 10
    Name: jackal
    Money: 100.989998

Comment: Exactly what are you expecting in the output which differs from what you get?

Comment: IMO you shouldn't have C++ tag.

Comment: There are a number of questions already about this. The problem is that scanf("%d") leaves the trailing newline in the input buffer, and then gets() reads that left-over newline character as a (very short) line.

Comment: Ok..I understand that I should use fgets to avoid problems related with whitespaces. But in my second o/p, how does first printf get to know that it has to stop printing after 10?why does not the first printf continue to print the ascii value of 'jackal'??

Comment: !!NEVER!! use `gets`. It is a gaping security hole. See the section from the manpage: *Never use gets().  Because it is impossible to tell without knowing the data in advance how many characters gets() will read, and because gets() will continue to store characters past the end of the buffer, it is extremely dangerous to use.  It has been used to  break  computer security.  Use `fgets()` instead.*

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not with `scanf` but `gets` - use [`fgets`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) instead.

> char * gets ( char * str );
>
> gets - Reads characters from the standard input (stdin) and stores them as a C string into str until a newline character or the end-of-file is reached.

Comment: Thanks for reply acme. I understand that scanf will remove any newline characters entered from console. So if i enter 10 and then press enter, should not '/n' be removed?and should not i be prompted for the input for string name?? sadly i dnot understand why my program does not behave this way.

Comment: `should not /n be removed?` No even scanf will not remove it automatically - you have to be careful while taking char inputs.

Comment: "scanf will remove any newline characters entered from console" is incorrect.  Directives/specifiers like `"%d"` and `"%f"` and  `" "` will consume (scan) in newline characters.  That is the result of the format string, not an inherent function of `scanf()`.

Comment: Thank you acme and @chux. Could you please explain the reason behind the second o/p? When i provide 10jackal as value for an int variable, the int variable takes up 10 and the string name takes up the value "jackal". how does scanf knows that it has to stop after reading 10 and that the second value "jackal" should be put under string?how come the int variable doesnot print the value 10 and ascii value of jackal?

Comment: @Kung-fu-panda Entering keys "10jackal<Enter>" or in C "10jackal\n", `scanf ()` does _not_ know it needs to stop on "0".  It continues on to "j".  `scanf()` knows its looking for an `int` because of the `"%d"` and since "j" is not part of an `int`, it sneakily puts it back into `stdin`.  The next evil `gets()` gets in "jackal\n" storing only the "jackal".

Answer (score 0):

1use `fgets` instead of `gets`... `gets` is bad.

The reason why `gets` is bad:

`gets` Reads characters from the standard input until `enter` (new line is encountered.) is pressed.

In your case, `name[10]`, and you are doing `gets(name)`. `gets` does not know how big the `name` is... If you enter 9 character, it is okay.
But what if you enter more than 9 char? `gets()` continues to write all the `char` past the memory which doesn't belong to you hence causing "`Undefined Behavior`"